# Too Many Re-Renders or Cannot Be Called Inside a Callback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to render one of two components based on whether a user is authenticated with Firebase. I have a Login component set to render if there is no authenticated user, or ReactRouter renders the logged in component if there is an authenticated user. However, I want to wait to render either of those outcomes until the authentication has been returned.

To do so, I'm trying to give  `user` a temporary value which is then updated. However I run into an error that there are either Too Many Re-Renders, or that I cannot call the function inside a callback.

Here is the code where I get the Too Many Re-Renders error:

```
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("pending");

  setUser(useAuthentication());

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Header />
      {user === "pending" && <div>Loading...</div>}
      {user !== "pending" && !user && <Login />}
      {user !== "pending" && user && <RouterProvider router={router} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

To address this, I tried to utilize useEffect so that authentication is only being checked once, however that resulted in the error that useAuthentication cannot be called inside a React Hook:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState("pending");

  useEffect(() => {
    setUser(useAuthentication());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Header />
      {user === "pending" && <div>Loading...</div>}
      {user !== "pending" && !user && <Login />}
      {user !== "pending" && user && <RouterProvider router={router} />}
    </div>
  );
```

Each time I look up these errors the recommendation is to use the other option which has set me into a vicious cycle of trying to address each error in different ways with no luck. What are my options here??

Comment: Can you make an example with the problem here? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new

Answer (score 0):

in the first example you are updating the state inside the body of the component and this is incorrect, in the second example you called a hook inside useEffect and this is incorrect, with your seconde example you are close you just have to take the result of `useAuthentication()` outside `useEffect`:

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState("pending");
const authenticatedUser = useAuthentication();

  useEffect(() => {
    setUser(authenticatedUser);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Header />
      {user === "pending" && <div>Loading...</div>}
      {user !== "pending" && !user && <Login />}
      {user !== "pending" && user && <RouterProvider router={router} />}
    </div>
  );
```

then set it to `setUser`